# Calculate rotation acording to drag of one edge

Tags: c#, silverlight, math, vector, geometry

My code is in C# (Silverlight) but it might have nothing to it. I'm trying to rotate element by draging one of its edges. In event I got dx and dy values so tried to calculate vector from rotation center to drag start and the other one from center to new location, and calculate angle between those vectors, but it didn't work. What would be correct way to do such thing?

Edit:
As MBo asked for code my try was to calculate angle between 2 vectors. Lets say `v[vx, vy]` is vector from rotation center to draged edge, then `vc[vcx, vcy]` is vector of drag change. The third vector is `v1[v1x, v1y]` which is from rotation center to 'new' location of draged edge.

```
normV = Math.Sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)
normV1 = Math.Sqrt(v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y)
vv1 = vx*v1x+vy*v1y // dot product of v and v1 vectors
// fi angle shoudl be
fi = Math.Acos(vv1 / (normV * normV1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives angle in half-range 0..Pi, it is necessary to add angle sign with cross product.

Let's (x0,y0) - initial captured point, (x1,y1) - after dragging, (cx, cy) - rotation center.

[image]

```
dx0 = x0-cx
dy0 = y0-cy
dx1 = x1-cx
dy1 = y1-cy
RotationAngle = Math.Atan2(dx0 * dy1 - dx1 * dy0, dx0 * dx1 + dy0 * dy1)
```

Comment: so it is better, as it almost works. At least rotation can be performed in both directions. The problem is, around 30 or 45 degrees is moment, when I loose track of Rotation Thumb and it messes up.

Comment: This code calculates signed angle P0-C-P1 in full range [-Pi..Pi) and must not fail at 30 or 45 degrees rotation. Probably, there is some confusion with points and drag change designation?

Comment: It might be. I try to drag Thumb in circle and after +-30deg cursor is out of Thumb, and after +-50deg circle movement of cursor fails rotating, but moving cursor in one direction (horizontal or vertical) increases angle and allows full, deterministic rotation of control. For me it would be ok, but for end user...

Comment: After transforming edge location using RenderTransform your solution works like it suppouse to.